French movie (comedy, I think) about a man who leaves his family
Don't even remember when I watched it (sometime in the 2000s). I can only remember a few moments from the movie:
I remember the man was being bothered by his wife and daughter all the time. 
The wife and daughter are watching a TV show they always watched on the couch and one day in that TV show there's a woman looking for a man who seems to be the main character in this movie (the husband). The wife and daughter are frozen with eyes wide open - Did the man they considered an idiot have a double life and story with another woman?
I think the man after that at some point leaves them and goes to live on a farm with the woman who was looking for him. I think the man had some kind of memory loss. 
There's one more thing I seem to remember, but, I'm not sure if this one is from this same movie. At some point the man is eating in a restaurant with a friend and then he suffers a kind of heart attack and hits his head against the table.
Also, I think that friend wants to have sex with the wife of the main character (who doesn't seem to care)-

Can you estimate the film's year of release (or even decade)?

It wasn't an old movie, probably from 2000's

Sounds like the French comedy Happiness Is in the Field from 1995.

Francis Bergeade, owner of a toilet seats and brushes' factory in Dole, has just turned 65 and his life is a misery. Tax services are harassing him, his snobby wife Nicole despises him, and his daughter whimsically wants to have an expensive wedding. Francis knows only moments of relief while having lunches or dinners in fancy restaurants with his best friend, car dealer Gérard. Stress become too overwhelming and while on a lunch, he suffers an attack from a blocked nerve.
During his convalescence, his family watch a reality television show about long-lost relationships and disappearances called "Où es-tu?" ("Where are you?"). Amongst the cases, a Spanish-born [farm] woman, Dolorès Thivart, and her daughters, "Zig" and "Puce" [...] are looking for their husband and father, Michel, who vanished 27 years ago. Michel Thivart happens to be Francis's exact lookalike.

Here are some clips from the film (interspersed with audience reactions):



